# Why does `ssh user@server mycommand` create an interactive shell?

Tags: bash, ssh

```
$ ssh t@localhost [[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'
Interactive
```

I was wondering why the above shell is interactive, given that It has nonoption arguments, and doesn't have `-s` or `-c` or `-i`.

From bash manual:

> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments, unless -s is specified, without specifying the -c option, and whose input and error output are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not performing the test you think you are.  Your expansion of `$-` is happening *before* the `ssh` command is executed.  To demonstrate:

```
$ set -x
$ ssh home echo $-
+ ssh home echo himxBHs
himxBHs
$ ssh home 'echo $-'
+ ssh home 'echo $-'
hBc
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you quote or escape my command to make it work?

Comment: Does `ssh` add `bash -c` when running the command?

Comment: @Tim, I would quote it thusly:  Either `ssh t@localhost '[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo "Interactive" || echo "Not interactive"'` to perform the string comparison test remotely, or `ssh t@localhost '[[ $- == *i* ]]' && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'` to do it locally.